# How to make safe PUT DELETE requests?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, backend

I am making backend for my project and I have a question about safety.

As an example my task is handle different "/notes" requests.

- /notes => get all notes of authorized user
- /notes => create new note
- /notes => delete note

So... Reciving data is safe. Noone can get these notes from another URL because of CORS.

If we will use GET params to create or delete notes
/notes?action=delete&note_id=7
bad people can send link to authorized user and he will lose his data by accident.

So next step is making POST requests.

Everything is much better, but there is still a little hole. If someone will add post form with hidden input params it can be dangerous.

So last thing that I'd add is sending extra param, that only authorized user knows.

- User ID
- Temporary hash

or something like that.

Is there any other solutions?

Comment: first of all define "safe." by the sound of the first part of your question, what you need is called **authorization** (different from authentication). the user id should not be available in the form input lest people can just edit that input directly - use something independent like session or something. also have you considered cross site request forgery (csrf) attacks? fyi, please ask one specific question at a time, "safe" is pretty broad.

Comment: I was trying to find a name of this type of attacks. CSRF. So this whole text was about CSRF and question was how to prevent CSRF attacks in the better way. I already found information about preventing this type of attacks. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
/notes?action=delete&note_id=7
```

You need a know id of owner note smt like that:

```
$note_id = (int)$_GET['note_id'];
$note = 'SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `id` = $note_id'; (fetch)
if($user['id'] == $note['user_id']) {
 //delete code
} else {
 exit('Bye bye');
}
```